# How to export the residuals of a random forest regression while using spatialsample?

Tags: r, random-forest, tidymodels

I am trying to replicate this [tutorial](https://juliasilge.com/blog/drought-in-tx/) but instead of a linear regression I am using random forest (RF). I can make the prediction but now I would like to compute and extract the residuals of the regression (i.e., observed - predicted values). Then, I would like to `cbind` the residuals with the coordinates of the `data.frame`, like so:

```
resids_df <- cbind(original_df[, 1:2], rf_resids) # where the original_df[, 1:2] contains the coordinates and the rf_resids are the residuals of the RF regression
```

The issue is that when after making the predictions, the output has 54 more values than my original data set (3792 vs 3738). This causes an issue because I can't `cbind` the residuals due to the difference in number of rows.

How can I resolve this issue and get exactly the same number of residuals (observations) as my original data set?

P.S. my data set does not contain NA values.

In the example below, I used asubset of my dataset but again, you can see that the there is 1 more value in the predictions compared to the number of rows in the data set.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(spatialsample)
library(sf)

wd <- "path/"

proj_ref_sys <- "EPSG:7760"

drought <- read.csv(paste0(wd, "block.data.csv"))
nrow(drought)
# [1] 60 !!!!!!!!!!!!!

drought_sf <- st_as_sf(drought, coords = c("x", "y"),  crs = proj_ref_sys)

set.seed(123)
folds <- spatial_block_cv(drought_sf, v = 3)

drought_res <-
  workflow(ntl ~ pop + agbh + nir, 
           rand_forest(mode = "regression", mtry = 2, trees = 100) %>%
             set_engine("randomForest")) %>%
  fit_resamples(folds, control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE))

drought_res

collect_predictions(drought_res)

# A tibble: **61** × 5 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   id    .pred  .row   ntl .config             
   <chr> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <chr>               
 1 Fold1 28.7     18  29.2 Preprocessor1_Model1
 2 Fold1 27.9     19  32.8 Preprocessor1_Model1
 3 Fold1 17.2     20  29.6 Preprocessor1_Model1
 4 Fold1 19.6     21  28.6 Preprocessor1_Model1
 5 Fold1 34.3     22  36.5 Preprocessor1_Model1
 6 Fold1 48.7     28  34.8 Preprocessor1_Model1
 7 Fold1 45.9     29  32.2 Preprocessor1_Model1
 8 Fold1 40.1     30  28.3 Preprocessor1_Model1
 9 Fold1 14.6     31  22.5 Preprocessor1_Model1
10 Fold1  9.96    32  17.1 Preprocessor1_Model1
# ℹ 51 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

The `data.frame` I'm using:

```
structure(list(x = c(995494.2549, 995924.2549, 996354.2549, 996784.2549, 
997214.2549, 997644.2549, 998074.2549, 998504.2549, 998934.2549, 
999364.2549, 999794.2549, 1000224.2549, 1000654.2549, 1001084.2549, 
1001514.2549, 1001944.2549, 1002374.2549, 1002804.2549, 1003234.2549, 
1003664.2549, 1004094.2549, 1004524.2549, 1004954.2549, 1005384.2549, 
1005814.2549, 1006244.2549, 1006674.2549, 1007104.2549, 1007534.2549, 
1007964.2549, 1008394.2549, 1008824.2549, 1009254.2549, 1009684.2549, 
1010114.2549, 1010544.2549, 1010974.2549, 1011404.2549, 1011834.2549, 
1012264.2549, 1012694.2549, 1013124.2549, 1013554.2549, 1013984.2549, 
1014414.2549, 1014844.2549, 1015274.2549, 1015704.2549, 1016134.2549, 
1016564.2549, 1016994.2549, 1017424.2549, 1017854.2549, 1018284.2549, 
1018714.2549, 995494.2549, 995924.2549, 996354.2549, 996784.2549, 
997214.2549), y = c(1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019421.5842, 1019421.5842, 1019421.5842, 
1019421.5842, 1019421.5842), ntl = c(9.14866638183594, 15.3856477737427, 
16.3302040100098, 12.454291343689, 10.4823837280273, 11.394606590271, 
8.1963529586792, 4.50725030899048, 3.95374751091003, 5.73203563690186, 
14.3955335617065, 17.0745468139648, 14.2944135665894, 10.333722114563, 
9.80743503570557, 12.5352020263672, 19.8813304901123, 29.2410221099854, 
32.8321876525879, 29.575023651123, 28.5894374847412, 36.4911346435547, 
49.4252128601074, 61.3118171691895, 58.6104736328125, 43.0437355041504, 
28.096061706543, 34.8003845214844, 32.1936340332031, 28.3407783508301, 
22.5178966522217, 17.0638084411621, 20.7549228668213, 18.3547439575195, 
10.2983675003052, 7.3524694442749, 7.17788362503052, 7.06999540328979, 
8.03957176208496, 12.6783542633057, 18.7537479400635, 26.1656856536865, 
36.539493560791, 41.0569839477539, 25.5366401672363, 15.7820110321045, 
9.87918758392334, 7.65169858932495, 6.96318626403809, 8.69833087921143, 
12.1393032073975, 15.151198387146, 14.5944147109985, 9.46016979217529, 
4.53868055343628, 12.8388118743896, 21.1265335083008, 19.3046970367432, 
10.5719947814941, 8.08844661712646), pop = c(31.2753772735596, 
55.8289375305176, 56.4003105163574, 33.795223236084, 31.0511913299561, 
30.5730743408203, 13.667106628418, 7.08161020278931, 6.89333772659302, 
13.9001550674438, 35.5272178649902, 42.4625587463379, 32.9688529968262, 
21.4302787780762, 12.6151924133301, 17.4939270019531, 38.1474113464355, 
60.8120536804199, 65.3665008544922, 53.8765907287598, 46.2705993652344, 
61.42333984375, 70.8307113647461, 53.3152236938477, 31.4083557128906, 
24.9810562133789, 38.3716621398926, 56.114860534668, 67.1656036376953, 
60.8404235839844, 33.7796592712402, 29.8311328887939, 44.3309173583984, 
31.9606342315674, 16.7053775787354, 10.1427822113037, 11.4020376205444, 
10.7794933319092, 18.2773151397705, 34.2912216186523, 50.6655197143555, 
52.1081962585449, 53.0502471923828, 59.4989013671875, 48.5897750854492, 
41.188159942627, 27.0699615478516, 11.5318984985352, 9.09538650512695, 
14.2379903793335, 24.8153190612793, 29.3468627929688, 30.5861835479736, 
15.3130531311035, 9.47307205200195, 37.2332077026367, 94.2268676757812, 
73.2485733032227, 26.8748569488525, 26.8519401550293), agbh = c(0.124395661056042, 
0.543155550956726, 0.930405616760254, 0.176615670323372, 0.122252210974693, 
1.86410081386566, 0.201039269566536, 0.00215102708898485, 0.00524011626839638, 
0.0221506990492344, 1.75632297992706, 0.954743504524231, 0.373224049806595, 
0.0127956680953503, 0.0007417316082865, 0.0123716788366437, 0.279229581356049, 
2.30779552459717, 2.58910322189331, 1.23243260383606, 0.819948613643646, 
1.74025285243988, 4.03071403503418, 2.78268098831177, 2.00978517532349, 
0.700970351696014, 0.196071043610573, 2.19463133811951, 4.83159875869751, 
2.20620393753052, 0.321354597806931, 0.00308413081802428, 1.737912774086, 
0.468539208173752, 0.0156131321564317, 0.00116395147051662, 0.0145542966201901, 
0.000892410753294826, 0.0419198162853718, 2.84171080589294, 3.22121715545654, 
2.73401832580566, 2.47091150283813, 2.10038590431213, 1.15651941299438, 
0.490403175354004, 0.0419915802776814, 0.101970501244068, 0.00181114906445146, 
0.0132269319146872, 0.212756171822548, 0.111757233738899, 1.2169703245163, 
0.129767879843712, 0, 0.582266986370087, 2.96843385696411, 1.16728830337524, 
0.0494964420795441, 0.0664984136819839), nir = c(0.261590600013733, 
0.250058531761169, 0.238313049077988, 0.246726274490356, 0.241509333252907, 
0.215491861104965, 0.25552836060524, 0.26755028963089, 0.283316373825073, 
0.2645283639431, 0.2347122579813, 0.250579416751862, 0.272739976644516, 
0.26601967215538, 0.260071456432343, 0.283827364444733, 0.270996034145355, 
0.229571804404259, 0.228905484080315, 0.240774929523468, 0.22843000292778, 
0.201068416237831, 0.174168020486832, 0.187955036759377, 0.235188364982605, 
0.226306527853012, 0.197943985462189, 0.192345812916756, 0.18694880604744, 
0.203041225671768, 0.24348683655262, 0.264572501182556, 0.234625786542892, 
0.252681404352188, 0.252072751522064, 0.241365790367126, 0.228045880794525, 
0.252986639738083, 0.261032313108444, 0.233464851975441, 0.235829710960388, 
0.235184907913208, 0.212146639823914, 0.204127430915833, 0.216947212815285, 
0.225598230957985, 0.231632620096207, 0.224976778030396, 0.219116434454918, 
0.255260914564133, 0.241265594959259, 0.237798929214478, 0.241482153534889, 
0.240964710712433, 0.252938002347946, 0.258243441581726, 0.211435839533806, 
0.217503502964973, 0.237074509263039, 0.237700119614601)), row.names = c(NA, 
60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you look at the .row column you'll see row 28 occurs twice, it appears in Fold1 and Fold2. Do you understand what this is doing?

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2023-11-14, for spatialsample >= 0.5.0:**

Thanks to your report here, this should be a much less common issue in new versions of spatialsample. If you're using version 0.5.0 or above, `spatial_block_cv()` now has an argument, `expand_bbox`, which will *very* slightly expand the area that the "grid" of blocks covers. This fixes the issue where, with regularly spaced data, you might have observations that fell into two folds:

```r
drought_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(
  expand.grid(
    x = seq(995494, 1018714, 430),
    y = seq(1019422, by = 430, length.out = 55)
  ),
  coords = c("x", "y"),
  crs = 7760
)

library(spatialsample)

spatial_block_cv(drought_sf)
#> #  10-fold spatial block cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    splits             id    
#>    <list>             <chr> 
#>  1 <split [2707/318]> Fold01
#>  2 <split [2739/286]> Fold02
#>  3 <split [2722/303]> Fold03
#>  4 <split [2711/314]> Fold04
#>  5 <split [2722/303]> Fold05
#>  6 <split [2739/286]> Fold06
#>  7 <split [2722/303]> Fold07
#>  8 <split [2717/308]> Fold08
#>  9 <split [2712/313]> Fold09
#> 10 <split [2734/291]> Fold10
```

Because this is an argument to the function, you can control the strength of this expansion factor (and set it to `0` to get the same blocks as in older versions). We can use this to show the other big change in newer versions of spatialsample: if an observation would be duplicated, spatialsample will throw an error:

```r
spatial_block_cv(drought_sf, expand_bbox = 0)
#> Error in `generate_folds_from_blocks()` at spatialsample/R/spatial_block_cv.R:204:2:
#> ! Some observations fell exactly on block boundaries, meaning they were assigned to multiple assessment sets unexpectedly.
#> ℹ Try setting a different `expand_bbox` value, an `offset`, or use a different number of folds.
#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. └─spatialsample::spatial_block_cv(drought_sf, expand_bbox = 0)
#>  2.   └─spatialsample (local) block_fun(method) at spatialsample/R/spatial_block_cv.R:129:4
#>  3.     └─spatialsample:::random_block_cv(...) at spatialsample/R/spatial_block_cv.R:106:4
#>  4.       └─spatialsample:::generate_folds_from_blocks(data, centroids, grid_blocks, v, n, radius, buffer) at spatialsample/R/spatial_block_cv.R:204:2
#>  5.         └─rlang::abort(...) at spatialsample/R/spatial_block_cv.R:264:4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Original answer, for spatialsample < 0.5.0:**

Because your data are regularly spaced, some of the grid cell borders are perfectly aligned with your data. Under the hood, spatialsample is using `sf::st_intersects()` to determine which observations intersect which grid blocks. When an observation is perfectly on the cell border, it winds up in both blocks' folds.

The fix is to offset your grid slightly so that the grid lines don't perfectly align with your observations. You can control this via the `offset` argument to `st_make_grid()`, which we can pass via `...` in `spatial_block_cv()`.

For example, using your drought data:

```r
drought <- structure(list(x = c(995494.2549, 995924.2549, 996354.2549, 996784.2549, 
                                997214.2549, 997644.2549, 998074.2549, 998504.2549, 998934.2549, 
                                999364.2549, 999794.2549, 1000224.2549, 1000654.2549, 1001084.2549, 
                                1001514.2549, 1001944.2549, 1002374.2549, 1002804.2549, 1003234.2549, 
                                1003664.2549, 1004094.2549, 1004524.2549, 1004954.2549, 1005384.2549, 
                                1005814.2549, 1006244.2549, 1006674.2549, 1007104.2549, 1007534.2549, 
                                1007964.2549, 1008394.2549, 1008824.2549, 1009254.2549, 1009684.2549, 
                                1010114.2549, 1010544.2549, 1010974.2549, 1011404.2549, 1011834.2549, 
                                1012264.2549, 1012694.2549, 1013124.2549, 1013554.2549, 1013984.2549, 
                                1014414.2549, 1014844.2549, 1015274.2549, 1015704.2549, 1016134.2549, 
                                1016564.2549, 1016994.2549, 1017424.2549, 1017854.2549, 1018284.2549, 
                                1018714.2549, 995494.2549, 995924.2549, 996354.2549, 996784.2549, 
                                997214.2549), y = c(1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 
                                                    1019851.5842, 1019851.5842, 1019421.5842, 1019421.5842, 1019421.5842, 
                                                    1019421.5842, 1019421.5842), ntl = c(9.14866638183594, 15.3856477737427, 
                                                                                         16.3302040100098, 12.454291343689, 10.4823837280273, 11.394606590271, 
                                                                                         8.1963529586792, 4.50725030899048, 3.95374751091003, 5.73203563690186, 
                                                                                         14.3955335617065, 17.0745468139648, 14.2944135665894, 10.333722114563, 
                                                                                         9.80743503570557, 12.5352020263672, 19.8813304901123, 29.2410221099854, 
                                                                                         32.8321876525879, 29.575023651123, 28.5894374847412, 36.4911346435547, 
                                                                                         49.4252128601074, 61.3118171691895, 58.6104736328125, 43.0437355041504, 
                                                                                         28.096061706543, 34.8003845214844, 32.1936340332031, 28.3407783508301, 
                                                                                         22.5178966522217, 17.0638084411621, 20.7549228668213, 18.3547439575195, 
                                                                                         10.2983675003052, 7.3524694442749, 7.17788362503052, 7.06999540328979, 
                                                                                         8.03957176208496, 12.6783542633057, 18.7537479400635, 26.1656856536865, 
                                                                                         36.539493560791, 41.0569839477539, 25.5366401672363, 15.7820110321045, 
                                                                                         9.87918758392334, 7.65169858932495, 6.96318626403809, 8.69833087921143, 
                                                                                         12.1393032073975, 15.151198387146, 14.5944147109985, 9.46016979217529, 
                                                                                         4.53868055343628, 12.8388118743896, 21.1265335083008, 19.3046970367432, 
                                                                                         10.5719947814941, 8.08844661712646), pop = c(31.2753772735596, 
                                                                                                                                      55.8289375305176, 56.4003105163574, 33.795223236084, 31.0511913299561, 
                                                                                                                                      30.5730743408203, 13.667106628418, 7.08161020278931, 6.89333772659302, 
                                                                                                                                      13.9001550674438, 35.5272178649902, 42.4625587463379, 32.9688529968262, 
                                                                                                                                      21.4302787780762, 12.6151924133301, 17.4939270019531, 38.1474113464355, 
                                                                                                                                      60.8120536804199, 65.3665008544922, 53.8765907287598, 46.2705993652344, 
                                                                                                                                      61.42333984375, 70.8307113647461, 53.3152236938477, 31.4083557128906, 
                                                                                                                                      24.9810562133789, 38.3716621398926, 56.114860534668, 67.1656036376953, 
                                                                                                                                      60.8404235839844, 33.7796592712402, 29.8311328887939, 44.3309173583984, 
                                                                                                                                      31.9606342315674, 16.7053775787354, 10.1427822113037, 11.4020376205444, 
                                                                                                                                      10.7794933319092, 18.2773151397705, 34.2912216186523, 50.6655197143555, 
                                                                                                                                      52.1081962585449, 53.0502471923828, 59.4989013671875, 48.5897750854492, 
                                                                                                                                      41.188159942627, 27.0699615478516, 11.5318984985352, 9.09538650512695, 
                                                                                                                                      14.2379903793335, 24.8153190612793, 29.3468627929688, 30.5861835479736, 
                                                                                                                                      15.3130531311035, 9.47307205200195, 37.2332077026367, 94.2268676757812, 
                                                                                                                                      73.2485733032227, 26.8748569488525, 26.8519401550293), agbh = c(0.124395661056042, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.543155550956726, 0.930405616760254, 0.176615670323372, 0.122252210974693, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      1.86410081386566, 0.201039269566536, 0.00215102708898485, 0.00524011626839638, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0221506990492344, 1.75632297992706, 0.954743504524231, 0.373224049806595, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0127956680953503, 0.0007417316082865, 0.0123716788366437, 0.279229581356049, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      2.30779552459717, 2.58910322189331, 1.23243260383606, 0.819948613643646, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      1.74025285243988, 4.03071403503418, 2.78268098831177, 2.00978517532349, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.700970351696014, 0.196071043610573, 2.19463133811951, 4.83159875869751, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      2.20620393753052, 0.321354597806931, 0.00308413081802428, 1.737912774086, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.468539208173752, 0.0156131321564317, 0.00116395147051662, 0.0145542966201901, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.000892410753294826, 0.0419198162853718, 2.84171080589294, 3.22121715545654, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      2.73401832580566, 2.47091150283813, 2.10038590431213, 1.15651941299438, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.490403175354004, 0.0419915802776814, 0.101970501244068, 0.00181114906445146, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0132269319146872, 0.212756171822548, 0.111757233738899, 1.2169703245163, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.129767879843712, 0, 0.582266986370087, 2.96843385696411, 1.16728830337524, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0494964420795441, 0.0664984136819839), nir = c(0.261590600013733, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.250058531761169, 0.238313049077988, 0.246726274490356, 0.241509333252907, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.215491861104965, 0.25552836060524, 0.26755028963089, 0.283316373825073, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.2645283639431, 0.2347122579813, 0.250579416751862, 0.272739976644516, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.26601967215538, 0.260071456432343, 0.283827364444733, 0.270996034145355, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.229571804404259, 0.228905484080315, 0.240774929523468, 0.22843000292778, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.201068416237831, 0.174168020486832, 0.187955036759377, 0.235188364982605, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.226306527853012, 0.197943985462189, 0.192345812916756, 0.18694880604744, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.203041225671768, 0.24348683655262, 0.264572501182556, 0.234625786542892, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.252681404352188, 0.252072751522064, 0.241365790367126, 0.228045880794525, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.252986639738083, 0.261032313108444, 0.233464851975441, 0.235829710960388, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.235184907913208, 0.212146639823914, 0.204127430915833, 0.216947212815285, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.225598230957985, 0.231632620096207, 0.224976778030396, 0.219116434454918, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.255260914564133, 0.241265594959259, 0.237798929214478, 0.241482153534889, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.240964710712433, 0.252938002347946, 0.258243441581726, 0.211435839533806, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.217503502964973, 0.237074509263039, 0.237700119614601)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                60L), class = "data.frame")
```

We can shift the grid by a meter and still get all observations in one of the folds, but without duplicating any observations:

```r
library(tidymodels)
library(spatialsample)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.1, GDAL 3.6.4, PROJ 9.1.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
proj_ref_sys <- "EPSG:7760"
drought_sf <- st_as_sf(drought, coords = c("x", "y"),  crs = proj_ref_sys)

set.seed(123)
# default: 61 observations in assessment
folds <- spatial_block_cv(drought_sf, v = 3)
vapply(
  seq_len(nrow(folds)), 
  function(i) nrow(assessment(get_rsplit(folds, i))),
  numeric(1)
) |> 
  sum()
#> [1] 61

set.seed(123)
# With a tiny offset: 60 observations as we'd expect
folds <- spatial_block_cv(
  drought_sf, 
  v = 3,
  # This is the change: move our grid by 1 meter
  offset = st_bbox(drought_sf)[c("xmin", "ymin")] - 1
)
vapply(
  seq_len(nrow(folds)), 
  function(i) nrow(assessment(get_rsplit(folds, i))),
  numeric(1)
) |> 
  sum()
#> [1] 60
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This isn't great that this was a silent problem, and I'm going to open a bug in spatialsample about this in a minute -- but I'm guessing that the first fix I implement is that this situation will cause an error (suggesting that you pass an explicit `offset`), because I don't think it's trivial to automatically find an offset for any user-provided data that's big enough to fix this problem without accidentally excluding observations.